# Why didn't anyone notice that Baki of the Sand killed Hayate of the Leaf?

Tags: naruto

I want to know when Baki killed Hayate Gekko in *Naruto* and we see Baki again in *Naruto Shippuden* where he plays an important role to protect Sand Village.

So, nobody knows that Baki killed Hayate Gekko?

Answer (score 1):

They did, but that was all brushed away when they realised the Hidden Sand was being played by Orochimaru (who had killed the 3rd Kazekage and taken his place), presumably the peace treaty with Konoha settled all disputed.